# LightGBM binary classification model: predicted score to class probability

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost, lightgbm

I'm training a LGBM model on a classification (binary) dataset.

```
import lightgbm as lgb
def lgb_train(train_set, features, train_label_col, sample_weight_col=None, hyp = hyp):
    train_data = lgb.Dataset(data=train_set[features], label=train_set[train_label_col],)
    model = lgb.train(
        train_set=train_data,
        params=hyp,
        num_boost_round=hyp['num_boost_round'],
    )        
    return model
```

`preds = np.array(model.predict(test_features))`

Now, the problem is: when I call the `predict` function, I get a score `[0.00012, 0.0035, 0.0000048]`, how can I calculate the probabilities of each class?

Comment: How are you running the prediction?

Comment: `model.predict(test_features)` @TYZ

Comment: How many samples do you have in your `test_features`? Is it 3? If so, those will be the probabilities of 0 for those data points in your `test_features`.

Comment: yes, for this example, 3 samples and I get 3 scores.

Comment: Then this should be the probabilities.

Comment: Thanks, can you add it as an answer with some reference? :)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comment section, you have 3 samples in your `test_features` and you got 3 scores from `model.predict`, those will be the probabilities for each sample.

Ref: https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.predict

Comment: I don't see where it says that it's predicting the probability of class 0, in the documentation, it just says score / predicted values. Can you clarify this?

Comment: and note, I don't use LGBM classifier. So, I don't have predict_proba method.

Answer (score 0):

The model predicts the probability of class 1.

Ref: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/5352